# jquery multiple selector with contains()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I've a lot of `<option>`s in a `<select>`and and extra attribute called `zip`

```
<SELECT id="city">
  <OPTION zip="AUC 1291 100005" value="1">City 1</OPTION>
  <OPTION zip=" 1295 100006" value="2">City 2</OPTION>
  <OPTION zip=" 1299 100008" value="3">City 3</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

Now I want to select the Option which Text or ZIP contains a string value, but the following code doens't work.

```
var val = '1291'; //Zip code
var x = $('#city option:contains('+val+'), #city zip:contains('+val+')').val();
```

Why?

Comment: Because there are no `zip` elements. `zip` is an **attribute** of the `option` elements in this case. You are looking for attribute selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/.

Comment: `zip` is not a valid html attribute, use `data-zip` instead. Besides that, your approach does not make that much sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to select the elements with attribute, taht value contains requested string, you have to use:

```
  var val = '1291'; //Zip code
  var x = $('#city option[zip*="' + val + '"]').val();
```

As mentioned: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

But as guys said, the better way is to have HTML5 `data-zip` attribute instead of `zip`

(just prefix with `data-`).

In this case, your selector will be:

```
  var x = $('#city option[data-zip*="' + val + '"]').val();
```

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

`contains` checks for inner elements not  for attributes, you should go with something like:

```
$('#city option').filter(function(){
    return this.innerHTML.indexOf(val) > -1 || 
           $(this).attr('zip').indexOf(val) > -1;
});
```

Note that `zip` is not a valid HTML attribute, it would be wise to use `data-zip` instead.

```
$('#city option').filter(function(){
    return this.innerHTML.indexOf(val) > -1 || 
           $(this).data('zip').indexOf(val) > -1;
});
```

Comment: that wouldn't work when I'am searching for "AU" even if AU in the code example would be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Here`s the answer to my questions. Tested and works :)

```
var x = $('#city option:contains('+val+'), #city [data-zip*='+val+']').val();
```